# Merge 2 Immutable JS Ordered Map objects

Tags: react-native, immutable.js, ordered-map

I am using Immutable JS as a redux store for my React Native App. I have 2 Ordered Map which is a Keyed Collection of Lists. When I try to merge these 2 Ordered Maps, if the keys overlap, then the data is being overwritten.

For eg: Consider I have 2 Ordered Maps with dates as their keys. When I merge them, if both of them have keys with the same date, the data of that key will be replaced. How can I concatenate them without losing data?

OrderedMap1: {
  '21-07-2017': List(10),
  '22-07-2017': List(10),
  '23-07-2017': List(10),
  '24-07-2017': List(10)
}

OrderedMap2: {
  '24-07-2017': List(5)
}

When I try to merge them, the data @ key '24-07-2017' gets replaced
OrderedMap1.merge(OrderedMap2) gives 
{
  '21-07-2017': List(10),
  '22-07-2017': List(10),
  '23-07-2017': List(10),
  '24-07-2017': List(5)
}

I have tried concat(), merge() and mergeDeep() methods

Comment: It would probably be easier to spot the issue if we could see a sample of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeWith is what you're looking for. In the `merger` function you can [`concat`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/concat) the lists.

According the the provided example for `mergeWith` it should look like this, I guess:

```
OrderedMap1.mergeWith(
    (dates1, dates2) => dates1.concat(dates2),
    OrderedMap2
)
```